# DataLoading stays on True

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using the code below. A form to update the record with the BL and Services. The `Debtor` gets returned to the razor.cs (I can see it in debug), but DataLoading stays on true. So the form is not showing. Anyone any tips?

**AddUpdate.razor.cs:**

```
protected async override void OnInitialized()
{
    if (DataLoading)
    {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        DataLoading = true;
        _debtor = await debtorBL.GetByIdAsync(DebtorId);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        DataLoading = false;
    }
}
```

**DebtorBL.razor:**

```
private readonly IDebtorService _debtorService;

public DebtorBL (IDebtorService debtorService)
{
    _debtorService = debtorService;
}

public async Task<Debtor> GetByIdAsync(int Id)
{
    return await _debtorService.GetByIdAsync(Id);
}
```

**IDebtorService.cs:**

```
public interface IDebtorService
{
    Task<bool> AddUpdateAsync(Debtor debtor);
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(int Id);
    Task<Debtor> GetByIdAsync(int Id);
    Task<List<Debtor>> GetAllAsync();
}
```

**DebtorService.cs:**

```
public class DebtorService : IDebtorService
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _factory;

    public DebtorService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public async Task<Debtor> GetByIdAsync(int Id)
    {
        using (var _db = _factory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            return await _db.Debtors.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Not rly seeing the problem. Any tips?

Comment: When I change `_debtor = await debtorBL.GetByIdAsync(DebtorId);` in AddUpdate.razor.cs to `_debtor = new();` the form does show. So something must be wrong with the return...

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a **NONO**  `async void`

```cs
protected async override void OnInitialized()
```

This is a synchronous method.  There's no `Task` for the caller to await, so the component lifecycle methods run to completion before the await completes.

```cs
_debtor = new();
```

Works because it's synchronous code: there's no yielding.

Use the `OnInitializedAsync` version.

```cs
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
```

Comment: Jeez how did I miss that like ten times.... Thanks! was looking at it for too long now